# HTML text list with explanation

Tags: html, list, text

I want to present a **basic text list** with explanation.
See screenshot (this was done in a text editor).

I was thinking of a html table, but I don't succeed in simulating this easily.
Any suggestions?

[image]

I would like to use a ***table*** instead of a ***div***, since this allows me to easily add new lines. Most html-editors allow to just use TAB to add a new line.

The problem is the css: *How can I get the lines close to each other?*

***DIV example (thanks Sylent):***

```css
.divClass {
  display: table-row;
}

.divClass div {
  padding: 3px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
    <div>description</div>
    <div>Descriptive test with info.</div>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
    <div>description</div>
    <div>Descriptive test with info.</div>
</div>
```

*** Table example:***

```css
.divClass {
  display: table-row;
}

.divClass div {
  padding: 3px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="divClass">
    <tr>
        <td>definition</td>
        <td>Descriptive test with info.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divClass">
        <td>definition</td>
        <td>Descriptive test with info.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'd like to show that text in that list? just for clarification.

Comment: A table is indeed a possible solution. If the contents of the table is variable, you will need to use some mechanism to _POPULATE_ it. You may simply use a JavaScript function that adds to the DOM the table or use some framework. In my case, I'm very fun of AngularJS (this is an old version but is very stable and rather easy to get used to it) where you can set a two-ways relation between JavaScript objects and what is shown in the page.

Comment: You'd like to use what instead of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made this with `<div>` and some CSS.

html:

```
<div class="divClass">
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divClass">
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.divClass {
  display: table-row;
}

.divClass div {
  padding: 3px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Hope this displays it well enough for you :D .